# Converting a dict to a dict of lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have dict that looks like:

```
d = {'col2': 'b', 'col1': 12}
```

This has been created from a Pandas DataFrame using:

```
df.ix[row,['col1','col2,]].to_dict()
```

I want to include this dict in the df.isin() method. However, when I do, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: only list-like or dict-like objects are allowed to be passed to DataFrame.isin(), you passed a 'int'
```

If I manually edit the dictionary to be:

```
d = {'col2': ['b'], 'col1': [12]}
```

...(i.e. a dict of lists) then the .isin() works as expected.

Unfortunately, manual editing is not an option. A very large number of such dicts need to be created automatically from large dataframes. What is the most efficient way to automatically create a dict of lists from a dataframe that can be included in .isin() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
d = {key: [value] for key, value in d.items()}
```

It's called a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I've played with list comprehensions and have heard to dictionary comprehensions but hadn't, until now, appreciated their value.